# Write a reusable reducer with redux-toolkit

Tags: redux, react-redux, redux-toolkit

I have several slices with the same logic for reducers like the below

```js
export const CounterASlice = createSlice({
  name: "counterA",
  initialState: { count: number },
  reducers: {
    incrementCounterA: (state, action: PayloadAction<number>) => {
      state.count += action.payload;
    },
    decrementCounterA: (state, action: PayloadAction<number>) => {
      state.count -= action.payload;
    },
  },
});
```

```js
export const CounterBSlice = createSlice({
  name: "counterB",
  initialState: { count: number },
  reducers: {
    incrementCounterB: (state, action: PayloadAction<number>) => {
      state.count += action.payload;
    },
    decrementCounterB: (state, action: PayloadAction<number>) => {
      state.count -= action.payload;
    },
  },
});
```

Previously I build common reducers based on [official documentation](https://redux.js.org/usage/structuring-reducers/reusing-reducer-logic), but what is the best way to have the same functionality in the redux toolkit?

**Edit**

What I am looking for is not defining a function for each action and assigning them again to each slice. I just want a reducer that gets a name and creates all actions based on like

```js
export const counterReducer = (name:string) => { ... }
```

then we can use it like

```js
export const CounterASlice = createSlice({
  name: "counterA",
  initialState: { count: number },
  reducers: counterReducer("A"),
  },
});
```

Answer (score 0):

`reducers` are functions like any other. You can reuse them:

```js
const incrementCounter = (state, action: PayloadAction<number>) => {
  state.count += action.payload;
}
const decrementCounter = (state, action: PayloadAction<number>) => {
  state.count -= action.payload;
}

const counterReducer = (name: string) => {
  return {
    ['incrementCounter' + name]: incrementCounter,
    ['decrementCounter' + name]: decrementCounter,
  }
}

export const CounterASlice = createSlice({
  name: "counterA",
  initialState: { count: number },
  reducers: {
    ...counterReducer('A'),
    // rest of counterA reducers
  },
});
export const CounterBSlice = createSlice({
  name: "counterB",
  initialState: { count: number },
  reducers: {
    ...counterReducer('B'),
    // rest of counterB reducers
  },
});
```